# Multi player game over internet using WPF/Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, p2p

What is the generic way to maintain state in multi-players game over internet, which can be played on GUI of WPF or Silverlight? One player might be on WPF gui and others might be on Silverlight GUI.

P2P, HTTP server or some other technique? please advise.

thanks, AJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of them can consume WCF / Web service, and your service connect to database.

Comment: true but what's the way to reflect the changes made by one player to other player machine? For both wpf and SL.